QGIS 3.28.11 Layout-View extremely slow and laggy when text is in the center of view and when moving label elements
When I'm working out a layout in QGIS i normally don't use the built in legend function as I don't like it. I create label elements and place them as i want them. When these are quite big and I'm panning over them the program gets extremely slow and laggy. Same when I'm trying to move a label element which almost makes it impossible to set them correctly. I just need to pan to a space without label elements (like the actual map) and it's working smooth again.
Can you explain what's going on to me?


No idea of what's happening but you should at last provide the QGIS version you are using, show the whole label setting (what do you mean by "When these are quite big") and try with a new profile to see if it work better and report on result...

Thanks for the reply. I edited the OP and tried a new profile, no changes.
